# Python seems to overwrite the result of previous function calls

Tags: python

I encountered a strange problem:

```py
import math

def deg2rad(d):
    return (d/180.0) * math.pi

class Rotor:
    def __init__(self, deg=0.0, x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0, direct=False):
        if direct:
            self.a = deg
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.z = z
        else:
            self.a = math.cos( deg/2.0 )
            sinD = math.sin( deg/2.0 )
            self.x = sinD * x
            self.y = sinD * y
            self.z = sinD * z
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Rotor: a={self.a} x={self.x} y={self.y} z={self.z}>"
    
    def __mul__(self, other):
        newA = self.a * other.a - self.x * other.x - self.y * other.y - self.z * other.z
        newX = self.x * other.a + other.x * self.a + self.y * other.z - self.z * other.y
        newY = self.y * other.a + other.y * self.a + self.z * other.x - self.x * other.z
        newZ = self.z * other.a + other.z * self.a + self.x * other.y - self.y * other.x
        
        return Rotor(newA, newX, newY, newZ, True)
    
    def reverse(self):
        return Rotor(self.a, -self.x, -self.y, -self.z, True)
    
    def rotVec(self, x, y, z):
        vX = 2 * (self.y * z - self.z * y)
        vY = 2 * (self.z * x - self.x * z)
        vZ = 2 * (self.x * y - self.y * x)
        
        rX = x + vX * self.a + ( self.y * vZ - self.z * vY )
        rY = y + vY * self.a + ( self.z * vX - self.x * vZ )
        rZ = z + vZ * self.a + ( self.x * vY - self.y * vX )
        
        return (rX, rY, rZ)

def rotX(rotor, deg):
    r = Rotor(deg, 1, 0, 0)
    return rotor * r * rotor.reverse()
```

When I test the above code with:

```py
r = Rotor() #(2)
r = rotX(r, deg2rad(90))
r = rotX(r, deg2rad(90))
r = rotX(r, deg2rad(180)) #(1)

print(r)
print( r.rotVec(1,0,0) )
print( r.rotVec(0,1,0) )
print( r.rotVec(0,0,1) )
```

then no mater what functions call are before `#(1)` the marked call seems to overwrite all previous `rotX(...)` calls. You can delete all above calls (except `#(2)`) and the program will behave the same. Right now it prints:

```
<Rotor: a=0.0 x=1.0 y=0.0 z=0.0>
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, -1.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, -1.0)
```

this is the result one can expect after only `#(1)` call.

What's going on?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, it sounds like you expect to print different values from "r = rotX(r, deg2rad(90))" and "r = rotX(r, deg2rad(180))", but you are changing the value of r on each of the those 3 lines, before you print it out.

Comment: I willingly admit that I am too lazy to try to figure out what this does (and what it is supposed to do). However, at a quick glance I see no obvious programming traps to fall into, which means that it is *probably* a straightforward debugging issue. I suggest you follow the advice given in Eric Lippert's ["How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you don't find out what is wrong, it will at least give you material for a more focused question.